# Django with json querydict and message

Tags: python, json, django

Once the request is received at `django`, i look up in db and send the dbresult to client using `json.dumps` and of course after applying `serializers`. Now if i need to send any failure message or exception to to client in json format. how can i do this. can i append the message to json. or is there a better way to do this.

If needed to append how can i append this to my json. this is my `json data`

```
  products = Products.objects.all()
  serialized = serializers.serialize("json", products) 
  json_data = json.dumps("json", serialized)

  message = "got all products" # or "success"
```

myjson output without message :

```
  [{"pk": 1, "model": "Analysis.product", "fields": {"product": "Books", "company": 1, "product_desc": "None", "product_id": null, "user": 2}}, {"pk": 2, "model": "Analysis.product", "fields": {"product": "Moveis", "company": 1, "product_desc": "None", "product_id": null, "user": 2}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make your own json object and then dump that object in `HttpResponse`

```
to_json = {
        "products": prodcuts,
        "message": "got all products"
    }
 serialized = serializers.serialize("json", to_json) 
 return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(to_json), mimetype='application/json')
```

Hope that helps!!